# How to stop https warning of untangle captive portal?

Tags: networking, android, firewall, https, gateway

How can stop https warning from displaying on webrowser if a client tries to connect through my network.
The scenario is:
As I have configured captive portal on untangle(it is a UTM) so if user tries to connect from my network from its mobile device using android so when it tries to open any website so the chrome shows https warning so its hard to a user to redirect automatically to the captive portal page.

So let me know if I can disable this https warning and I want that the android user as soon as it connects  to the network it should automatically get redirected to captive portal page without any https warnning.

Answer (score 0):

Upload a valid certificate with a valid certification path (to a global root CA) to your captive portal and provide it to the connecting clients.

Or use HTTP.

A third option to force users to install your self-signed certificate is possible, but probably impractical in this scenario.

Comment: How can I provide a valid global certificate without proper FQDN

Comment: You cannot. That's the whole point of PKI.